# Firestore | orderBy(votes) combined with startAfter() excludes docs with 0 votes

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I found an unusual thing while I was creating queries.
If `orderBy(votes)` and `startAfter(...)` are combined, **all the docs in which votes value equal to 0**, are not retrieved.

Example code:

```
  let queryConstraints = [
    limit(5),
    orderBy('votes', 'asc'),
    startAfter(lastVisibleDocRef ?? 0)
  ]

  const query = query(
    collection(getFirestore(), 'path'),
    ...queryConstraints,
  )

  getDocs(query)
```

Everything else is working correctly, the unique problem is with docs with the value of the "votes" field equal to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling it to start after `0` if there's no `lastVisibleDocRef`, so that probably explains:

```
startAfter(lastVisibleDocRef ?? 0)
```

My guess is that you only want to add a `startAfter` clause if `lastVisibleDocRef` has a value, for example with:

```
let queryConstraints = [
  limit(5),
  orderBy('votes', 'asc')
]
if (lastVisibleDocRef) {
  queryConstraints.push*startAfter(lastVisibleDocRef))
}
```